# Can not display a single mesh as solid

Tags: 3d-view

I am switching from an old version of Blender to the newest one. But I found that the texture still shows even though I set the Viewport Display to "Solid". Does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Are you in Rendered/Material preview mode? Try pushing Z/Shift Z to open the render view mode pie menu and switch to "Solid" there.

Comment: You don't show the top menu, but I'm quite sure you're in _Material Preview_ mode. The _Display As_ option is for _Solid View_ only. It will not affect the _Material Preview_ or the _Rendered View_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot looks like you're in *Material Preview* mode. The settings "Solid" and "Textured" under *Object Properties* > *Viewport Display* > *Display As* are only to choose different display color modes for *Solid* mode. (Because the other modes already determine what surface color to show: either a preview of the material or how it looks rendered.)

[image: solid mode]

Here is a "short" summary with examples what all the options for *Solid* mode mean. In *Solid* mode, you have six different coloring methods to choose from:

1. Material
2. Object
3. Attribute
4. Single
5. Random
6. Texture

With ***Single*** you can choose a single color for all objects in the viewport or ***Random*** lets Blender give different random colors, to each object its own.

First of all, I show you an object in *Material Preview*. This mode shows, what the actual *Material Output* nodes of the assigned materials produce. In my example, the cube has two materials: a green/orange material and a blue material on the front face.

[image: material preview]

Now I switch to *Solid* view, the default color option is usually ***Material***. In this case the object shows the colors which are set in the *Material Properties* under *Viewport Display*. Each material can have its own display color.

[image: solid > material]

If you choose the option ***Color***, the cube will show the color that's set under *Object Properties* > *Viewport Display* > *Color*. Since this color is set per object, it will always only show this one color, no matter how many materials it has.

[image: solid > object]

The most confusing option for *Solid* mode might be ***Attribute***. It looks by default as if it was the same as *Object*, but that's just as long as there are no *Color Attributes* on the object. They are located under *Object Data Properties* and hold for example vertex paint maps. Other than the modes before, the displayed color(s) can change because it will always show the **active** color attribute, i.e. the one that's selected (no matter if it's set to use for rendering or not).

[image: solid > attribute]

The last option to explain is ***Texture*** - and this is the only one where it makes a difference if the *Display As* setting is on "Solid" or "Textured". With "Solid" enabled, it will only show the colors from the material settings. With "Textured" enabled, it will show *Image Textures* which are in the material - no matter if they are connected to the material output or not. If there's only one, it will show that. If there are multiple textures, it will show the selected one or (if none is selected) the one which was the last one selected. And important: only images, other texture nodes like *Noise*, *Voronoi* etc. will only show the material color if they are selected (or were the last selected texture).

[image: solid > textures]

Comment: My question is solved. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Kevin You're welcome. You might consider accepting one of these answers as  the solution?

Comment: I just selected it, let me know if it does not show up

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear in what mode you are.

If you are in *Solid* mode, which is the mode where you can display the color you're highlighting, once you've chosen your color in the *Object panel > Viewport Display* you need to go into the *Viewport Shading* panel and choose *Object*:

[image]

If you want to change the material only for a custom color you need to stay in *Material* mode in the *Viewport Shading* panel then go into the *Material panel > Viewport Display* and choose your color:

[image]

Comment: Actually that's not correct. To show the color chosen in the _Viewport Display_ settings you have to switch to _Object_. If you switch to _Attribute_ it will show the active color attribute. It only shows the object color as default when there is no color attribute.

Comment: oh sorry I'm going to correct

Comment: @moonboots Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First question to clarify:

In what view are you right now in that picture?

[image]

After clarification, I am still a bit confused about what you are trying to achieve... Viewport Display in Object Properties is not meant to be used for that, it doesn't even activate your texture if you change it to the texture, you are in the wrong settings.

What about this part?

[image]

Or this part?

[image]

I will later edit this answer when you clarify those few things

Comment: Thanks for the help! My question is already solved